¿Cómo definir la misma altura para varios Multicell, utilizando TCPDF?
Actualmente realizo una consulta a la base de datos, luego muestro la información en 5 Multicell distintos, el objetivo de esto, es que se muestren los 5 Multicell con la misma altura, lo anterior lo logre con el apoyo de otros foros, en donde se calcula el estimado de líneas que ocupara el Multicell con más texto. El resultado es el siguiente.

Ahora el problema es que, la columna Descripción se almacena en la base de datos por medio de un editor HTML, cuando se aplica formato al texto, saltos de línea, etc, el cálculo de la altura no es el correcto y los MultiCell no se muestran con la misma altura, teniendo como resultado lo siguiente.

Entonces, mi pregunta es, ¿Se puede calcular la altura de un MultiCell con contenido HTML.
El código para obtener la altura de MultiCell es el siguiente.
$campo_uno = $this->Pdf->getNumLines($rs->fields[0], 93.5)*5;                
$campo_dos = $this->Pdf->getNumLines($rs->fields[1], 20)*5; 
$campo_tres = $this->Pdf->getNumLines($rs->fields[2], 30)*5;
$campo_cuatro = $this->Pdf->getNumLines($rs->fields[3], 20)*5;
$campo_cinco = $this->Pdf->getNumLines($rs->fields[4], 30)*5;
    
$array = array($campo_uno, $campo_dos, $campo_tres, $campo_cuatro, $campo_cinco);
rsort($array);
$h_cell= $array[0];

Al tener la altura calculada, se crean 5 MultiCell con la misma altura, que se calculo anteriormente.
$this->Pdf->MultiCell(93.5, $h_cell, $rs->fields[0], 1,'L', true, 0, '', '', true, 0, true, false, 0, 'M', true);
$this->Pdf->MultiCell(20, $h_cell,  number_format($rs->fields[1], 0)."%", 1, 'R', true, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, false, 0, 'T', true);
$this->Pdf->MultiCell(30, $h_cell,$rs->fields[2], 1, 'R', true, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, false, 0, 'T', true);
$this->Pdf->MultiCell(20, $h_cell,$rs->fields[3], 1, 'R', true, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, false, 0, 'T', true);
$this->Pdf->MultiCell(30, $h_cell,$rs->fields[4], 1,'R', true, 1, '', '', true, 0, false, false, 0, 'T', true);


Primero que nada, es mala práctica que llames a tu variables campo_X dado que no hay forma de saber que es lo que estás metiendo realmente al momento de leer.
Ahora, veo que tienes $h_cell= $array[0]; para la altura, la cual tratas de dar a todos, y mi pregunta es ¿Qué es $array[0]?, ¿Es una constante?, ¿Es una proporcional?, no hay manera de saberlo.
Segundo, si necesitas trabajar la altura, deberías fijar esa variable de alguna manera, para poder trabajar SOLAMENTE esa variable, y no confundirla posteriormente.
Buscando por ahí, eh encontrado que multicell, tiene muchos parámetros.
TCPDF::MultiCell( $w,  $h,  $txt,  $border,  $align = 'J',  $fill = false,  $ln = 1,  $x = '',  $y = '',  $reseth = true,  $stretch,  $ishtml = false,  $autopadding = true,  $maxh,  $valign = 'T',  $fitcell = false )

Y en este caso $h es Cell minimum height, es decir, altura mínima de la celda. Por lo que claramente vas a tener diferencias si solo trabajas la altura mínima, si el contenido es más largo, el alto seguirá variando.
Hay un par de variables que deberías revisar como, $reseth, $stretch, $maxh y $fitcell.
Al parecer lo que tu buscas, podría estar al darle uso a $fitcell.
Primero entonces, recomiendo corregir los errores con $h, y fijar un alto a todo, para luego trabajar con el resto. Recuerda que $array[0]

Agradezco tu comentario y pondré en práctica tus recomendaciones. Te comento que $array[0] recupera el valor mayor de rsort($array). El proceso es el siguiente: se crea una matriz con las 5 variables ($campo_1, $campo_2, ...), con rsort($array) se ordena la matriz de mayor a menor, con $h_cell= $matriz[0] se asigna el valor mayor a la variable $h_cell, que en teoría es la altura que deben tener todos los multicell.
